# scale along normals doesnt connect the edges

Tags: normals, scale

So i have been following this video tutorial https://youtu.be/jBqYTgaFDxU?t=1628 up until the timestamp everything is good, then he proceeds to using Alt+S to Scale along the Normals and he gets his result with the edges/faces(not sure which) connected i tried following everything exactly the same but it doesnt work out for me because what happens when i do it is this[image]
I hope someone can help me as to exactly what im doing wrong and yes there have been similar things on this side but they havent resolved my problem so i am forced to ask this question again.

Comment: Looks like you need to do "merge by distance" (Alt+M) to remove double vertices you might have produced accidentally. After that it should work as expected.

Comment: oh thank you so much that imediately cleared all my problems, thank you very much